# How can I create my own custom binary hierarchy type archive format?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a game using LWJGL, and I want to create a way so people can't edit the game data (models, textures, audio, etc...). I was wondering if it's possible to create a hierarchy type archive (like an archive with folders that contain other files), but is in my own format so only my program knows how to read/write it? I was thinking something along the lines of the .BSA format (used in Bethesda's games like Skyrim and Fallout). I have no idea how to approach this and even create a reader/writer for it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: But how can I create it? I have no Ida how to even do it